# Extract corresponding df value with reference from another df

Tags: python, pandas

There are 2 dataframes with 1 to 1 correspondence. I can retrieve an `idxmax` from all columns in `df1`.

Input:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ref':[2,4,6,8,10,12,14],'value1':[76,23,43,34,0,78,34],'value2':[1,45,8,0,76,45,56]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ref':[2,4,6,8,10,12,14],'value1_pair':[0,0,0,0,180,180,90],'value2_pair':[0,0,0,0,90,180,90]})

df=df1.loc[df1.iloc[:,1:].idxmax(), 'ref']
```

Output: df1, df2 and df

```
     ref  value1  value2
0    2      76       1
1    4      23      45
2    6      43       8
3    8      34       0
4   10       0      76
5   12      78      45
6   14      34      56  

     ref  value1_pair  value2_pair
0    2            0            0
1    4            0            0
2    6            0            0
3    8            0            0
4   10          180           90
5   12          180          180
6   14           90           90

    5    12
    4    10
Name: ref, dtype: int64
```

Now I want to create a df which contains 3 columns

Desired Output `df`:

```
ref   max value   corresponding value
12    78          180
10    76          90
```

What are the best options to extract the corresponding values from `df2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is matching the columns between `df1` and `df2`. Let's rename them properly, melt both dataframes, merge and extract:

```
(df1.melt('ref')
    .merge(df2.rename(columns={'value1_pair':'value1', 
                               'value2_pair':'value2'})
              .melt('ref'), 
           on=['ref', 'variable'])
    .sort_values('value_x')
    .groupby('variable').last()
)
```

Output:

```
          ref  value_x  value_y
variable                       
value1     12       78      180
value2     10       76       90
```

Comment: hi Quang Hoang. Your output on the last row should read 10 76 90....?

Comment: many thanks for the new functions melt and groupby!